# Undefined index error on line 9

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
echo "0LIV3R 's first game";
require("DatabaseObject.php");
require("databaseVars.php");
$database= new DatabaseObject($host, $username, $password, $database);

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_POST['login'])
{
    $username=$database->clean($_POST['username']);
    $password=$database->clean($_POST['password']);

    $result = $database->query("SELECT 'id','username','password' FROM 'users' WHERE 'username'='$username' LIMIT 1");
    try{
        if($database->num_rows($result) == 0){
            throw new Exception('User doesnot exist!');
        }
        $user = $database->fetch($result);
        if(md5($password) != $user['password']){
            throw new Exception('Invalid username/password!');
        }
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];

    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
/*DISPLAY*/
//echo"<h3 style='text-align:center;'>WAR LEGENDS</h3>";
$output = ob_get_clean();
require('templates/header.php');
echo "<p style='text-align:center;'>". $output ."</p>";

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    //require('templates/layout.php');
    echo "Welcome to War Legends<br/>";
}
else{
echo"<form action='./' method='POST'>
Username: <input type='text' name='username'/><br/>
password: <input type='password' name='password'/><br/>
<input type='submit' name='login' value='Register'/>
</form>";
}
require('templates/footer.php');

?>
```

i was trying to code online rpg login and got error in index i cant find a solution pls help
this is my code and i donno how to fix this
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: login in C:\wamp\www\myrpg\index.php on line 9
this is error

Comment: Check the "clean" function

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the array `$_POST` doesn't has an element named `login`. So please check why this happens. Probably it is because the posted form doesn't have this.

Comment: but i cant fix it edited code will be appreciated

Comment: give me your html code

Comment: i mean, who calls this page

Answer (score 0):

In your First `if` you are using `$_POST['login']` - try using it with `!empty()` or `isset()` function like this: `!empty($_POST['login'])`